# Change a character in a string to a string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write code in C that will take a string, check each character for a specific character (call it `'x'`), and if the character is `'x'`, change it to multiple characters (like `"yz"`). Here is my attempt, assuming buffer and replace are defined arrays of characters (i.e. `char buffer[400] = jbxyfgextd...; char replace[250];`)

```
  int j = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < 110; j++) {
    if (buffer[j]=='x') {
      int len = strlen(replace);
      replace[len] = 'y';
      replace[len+1] = 'z';
    }
    else {
      replace[j]=buffer[j];
    }
  }
```

When I run this I get some `y`'s and `z`'s, but they are not back to back. Is there any procedure/function to do this easily?

Comment: Do you initialize you replace[250] to all '\0' ?

Answer (score 2):

Because index in `buffer[]` and `replace[]` arrays are not same. Use two indexes separately.

In your code expression: `replace[j] = buffer[j];`  is wrong. You can correct it like:

```
 else {
      int len = strlen(replace);
      replace[len]=buffer[j];
 }
```

But to use `strlen()`, array `replace[]` should be nul `\0` terminated. (declare replace as `char replace[250] = {0}`)

**Edit:**

To write better code use two septate indexes as I suggested above -- code will be efficient and simplified.

```
int bi = 0;  // buffer index 
int ri = 0;  // replace index 
for (bi = 0; bi < 110; bi++) {
    if (buffer[bi] == 'x') {      
      replace[ri++] = 'y';
      replace[ri] = 'z';
    }
    else {
      replace[ri] = buffer[bi];
    }
    replace[++ri] = '\0'; // terminated with nul to make it string   
}
```

Comment: I am adding a new answer about the `\0`, but notice you already edit, give you a up :)

Comment: @LidongGuo Yes I precisely reading code again I notice OP is using strlen() function. Thanks  Lidong!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{

  // Pass through the array once counting the number of chars the final string
  // will need then allocate the new string

  char buffer[] = "this x is a text test";

  char replacement[] = "yz";
  unsigned int replaceSize = strlen(replacement);

  unsigned int bufferSize = 0;
  unsigned int newSize = 0;

  // calculate the current size and new size strings
  // based on the replacement size

  char *x = buffer;
  while (*x)
  {
    if ( *x == 'x' )
    {
      newSize+=replaceSize;
    }
    else
    {
      ++newSize;
    }
    ++x;
    ++bufferSize;
  }

  // allocate the new string with the new size 
  // and assign the items to it
  char *newString = new char[newSize];
  unsigned int newIndex = 0;
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i )
  {
    if ( buffer[i] == 'x' )
    {
      for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < replaceSize ; ++j )
      {
        newString[newIndex++] = replacement[j];
      }
    }
    else
    {
      newString[newIndex++] = buffer[i];
    }
  }

  std::string originalS ( buffer );
  std::string newS ( newString );

  std::cout << "Original: " << originalS << std::endl;
  std::cout << "New: " << newS << std::endl;

  delete newString;

}
```

Comment: Original: this x is a text test
New: this yz is a teyzt test